# Display multi-file org agenda as a sparse tree?

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs, org-agenda

`org-sparse-tree` function lists selected information with the headline structure above it.
This is useful when the meaning of org headings depends on context:

<kbd>SPC m T</kbd> `(org-show-todo-tree)`

[image]

`org-agenda` function prints the headings out of context, which can make the headings incomprehensible:

<kbd>SPC a o o s</kbd>   `Phrase: TODO (org-agenda, list all entries with keyword "TODO")`

[image]

As far as I know, org-sparse-tree only works on one org file at a time.
While org-agenda is derived from multiple org files.

Is there a way to display an agenda as a sparse tree? (when the agenda is derived from multiple files)

Alternatively, I could combine all my org project files into one. Is that the "org-mode way"?
If not, I will customize org-mode after gaining more org-mode experience.

I am using Emacs 25.2.1 with Spacemacs, evil, and ivy on Linux.

The remainder of this question describes what I have tried so far.

googled: `org-mode` `agenda` `sparse tree`

I tried the `org-occur-in-agenda-files` function:

<kbd>SPC a o /</kbd>

```
Org-files matching: tasks.org
Searched 5 buffers; no matches for "tasks.org"
```

What should be entered after the "Org-files matching" prompt?

From my ~/.spacemacs file:

```
(setq org-agenda-files (list
                    "~/Documents/developer/editors/emacs/tasks_demo/proj1/notes1.org"
                    "~/Documents/developer/editors/emacs/tasks_demo/proj1/tasks.org"

                    "~/Documents/developer/editors/emacs/tasks_demo/proj2_per/notes2.org"
                    "~/Documents/developer/editors/emacs/tasks_demo/proj2_per/tasks.org"

                    "~/Documents/developer/editors/emacs/tasks_demo/tasks.org"
                    ))
```

This google search found none: "org-occur-in-agenda-files" "Org-files matching"

**UPDATE_1**

This works:
Search all the org files with org-agenda, and if a heading needs context, <kbd>ENT</kbd> on the heading, which opens the heading in the same window.
<kbd>SPC b b</kbd> (ivy-switch-buffer) *Org Agenda* returns window to the agenda.
Is there a faster way to jump back to agenda?
<kbd>C-c &</kbd> (org-mark-ring-goto) does not jump back to agenda.

This works:
Search all the org files with org-agenda, and if a heading needs context, <kbd>mouse-3</kbd> on the heading, which opens the heading in another window.
But if another window is already open, that window's buffer is displaced.
Is there a way to open the agenda heading in a new window?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the <kbd>C-c a</kbd> for `org-agenda` and then <kbd>/</kbd> that is the [Multi-occur](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/advanced-searching.html#multi-occur) option?

According to the Org-mode Tutorial on topic [Advanced Searching](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/advanced-searching.html):

> Org-mode uses Emacs' multi-occur command to search for any lines in the agenda files containing a regular expression. Simply type C-c a / followed by a word or regular expression and you will be presented a buffer with all lines that match the query, with each line conveniently linked to its original location.

Still in the same topic:

> The commands we have examined so far typically search multiple files and display the resulting heading in a separate agenda buffer. But sometimes, you might want to search for various types of data ***within a single file***, so as to see all the matching headlines and entries in context.
>
> The way to accomplish this is via a `sparse tree view` (<kbd>C-c /</kbd>), which collapses the outline in the current file, showing only the portions that match a query.

So, if you want to make your search on all files you should start with `Multi-occur` and then use sparse trees on specific files.

Also, if you use Spacemacs I recommend you to make use of some shortcuts that starts with <kbd>,</kbd> (comma). You will find that, for example, `org-agenda` is accessible with just <kbd>, a</kbd> (`comma`, `a`), instead of <kbd>SPC a o o</kbd>.

Other examples:

`org-show-todo-tree`: <kbd>, T</kbd> = <kbd>SPC m T</kbd>

`org-sparse-tree`: <kbd>, /</kbd> = <kbd>SPC m /</kbd>

`org-clock-in`: <kbd>, I</kbd> = <kbd>SPC m I</kbd>

etc...

> The remainder of this question describes what I have tried so far.
>
> googled: org-mode agenda sparse tree

- Best resources on this topic are the Worg's [Advanced search](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/advanced-searching.html) Tutorial and the Org-Mode [Online Manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/index.html)

Comment: I forgot about the http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/index.html  
Worg's "Advanced searching" tutorial is a great resource.  
And thanks for showing how to accesses org-agenda with ", a".  
I appended **UPDATE_1** to the question.

Comment: You're welcome! What about multi-occur? It helped you out or you still need some other specific functionality?

Comment: Multi-occur is not what I needed.
SPC a o /  (org-occur-in-agenda-files) narrows the agenda results, but it does not display context.
Partial work around is described in main question under **UPDATE_1**.
Please read my questions under **UPDATE_1**.